# activex component can't create object 429 excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code in VBA that allows me to control the GUI of a software, I can run the code on my personal computer. I have tried running the same code on other computers but this message shows up: "Run-time error 429" ActiveX component can't create object.

Here is my code up to the line where the message shows up:

```
Sub GetAllFileNames()
Dim FileName As String
Dim strDirectory As String
Dim path As String
Dim index As Integer
Dim Block As Integer
Dim boot As Integer
Dim week As Integer

Dim Coor_x As Variant
Dim Coor_y As Variant
Dim East(1 To 5) As Variant
Dim North(1 To 5) As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Dim Factory As Rvea0334.Rvea0334Classes
Dim Workspace As IWaspWorkspace
Dim Project As IWaspProject


Set Factory = New Rvea0334Classes '(here I have the problem)
```

Rvea0334 is already available in References

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Always helps to post your code, and indicate where the error occurs.

Comment: So the problem is with the declaration, not creating a new instance of the object?  That doesn't match with the error message you posted

Comment: Sorry @TimWilliams, I made a mistake, this is the line: Set Factory = New Rvea0334Classes

Comment: On the PC with the problem is that reference tagged as "missing"?  Is the component you're trying to create installed there? Have you tried `Set Factory = New Rvea0334.Rvea0334Classes`  ?

Comment: Yes, I checked on the PC with the problem (tools>references)  Rvea0334 and Rvea0334Interfaces are available.
Could it be related to problems by admin permission?

Comment: Maybe - seems like this is maybe a custom component?  Privileges or antivirus/etc

Comment: Ok Tim, is there something I can try?

Comment: Sorry can't really offer much  - maybe start here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/activex-component-can-t-create-object-or-return-reference-to-this-object-error-4

Comment: Ok, thank you for the support